# Bloquear elemento por mais ou menos 10 minutos

Tags: php

Não vou postar meu código pra não passar vergonha mas alguém tem ideia de como bloquear uma div por algum tempo definido ? Após clicar nesta div ela some e depois do tempo definido ela aparecerá de novo.

Comment: Posta o código Will. Será mais fácil para ajuda-lo.

Answer (score 1):

Aqui está um código limpo e fiz do jeito que entendi na sua pergunta:

```
<?php

//Salva esse tempo na tabela, você pode alterar +10 pra qualquer outro valor
$tempoAtual = strtotime('+10 minutes');

//Onde $tempoDB é o $tempoAtual que foi salvo na DB
$timer = ceil(($tempoDB - time()) / 60);

//Se o tempo guardado na DB ainda for maior que o tempo atual, conteúdo ficará bloqueado
if ($tempoDB > time()) {
    //bloqueado
}
```

Veja referência de [ceil](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ceil.php)

Obs: A explicação está nos comentários de cada linha feita no código. E o `$timer` é apenas formatação, do tempo pra não ficar aquele monte de números, ele retorna apenas os minutos decaindo.

Comment: Opa deu certo. Até mostrei uma mensagem dizendo o tempo que ele poderá voltar e ver a div novamente