# Usuários ativos no site

Tags: php

minha intenção é criar um sistema de pessoas onlines no meu site, a cada 30s eu mando uma requisição em ajax pro meu servidor e marco o ip e a hora da visita, minha duvida é a seguinte no meu banco eu gravo no campo hora ( 03:29 ) usando a função date como posso estar comparando esta hora gravada com meu banco com a hora atual e saber se já se passaram 30 segundos ? pois assim quando se passa 30 segundos eu deleto do banco de dados as visitas ativas

Comment: Talves isso te ajude [Veja](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264889/bloquear-elemento-por-mais-ou-menos-10-minutos/264893#264893)

Answer (score 0):

> usando a função date como posso estar comparando esta hora gravada com meu banco com a hora atual e saber se já se passaram 30 segundos ?

Responde a essa pergunta, vamos lá.

Para fazer isso não precisa utilizar a função `date` (apesar de ser possível), mas nesse caso é melhor utilizar apenas a função `strtotime` ou `strftime`, você pode converter a data para segundos ou milissegundos e fazer a substração dos novos dados com os dados antigos.

```
<?php

/* Captura o tempo em segundos desde 1970 */
$date1 = strtotime("2018-01-06 02:43:00"); //Output: 1515206580
$date2 = strtotime("2018-01-06 02:43:32"); //Output: 1515206612

/* Utilize strtotime("+30 seconds") para capturar a data atual + 30 segundos */

/* Substrai as datas e verifica se $data é maior que 30 (Segundos) */
if ( ($date2 - $date1) > 30 ) {
    echo "Já se passaram mais de 30 segundos";
}
```

Caso queira fazer com `DateTime` e `DateInterval`, também é possível:

```
<?php

/* Instancia o objeto com as respectivas datas */
$date1 = new DateTime("2018-01-06 02:43:00");
$date2 = new DateTime("2018-01-06 02:43:32");

/* Captura a diferença entre a $data2 e $data1 */
$interval = $date2->diff($date1);

/* Captura a diferença em segundos e verifica se é maior que 30 */
if ($interval->format("%s") > 30) {
    echo "Já se passaram mais de 30 segundos";
}
```

Ou ainda:

```
<?php

/* Instancia o objeto com uma data. Para capturar a data/hora atual, deixe em branco ou passe o valor "now" */
$date1 = new DateTime("2018-01-06 02:43:00");

/* Adiciona 30 segundos a data anterior */
$date1->add(new DateInterval("PT30S"));

/* Verifica se a data atual é maior que a data anterior, somado os 30 segundos. */
var_dump( $date1->format("U") < time() );
```